# TypeError: Argument has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got numpy.bool_)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am now working on Cython where I need to define the NumPy array type and dimension before running the code. I have these coordinates (x,y) as input:

```
list_a = [(2, 16), (24, 26)]
list_b = [(18, 8), (30, 22)]
```

Since I use NumPy, I transform the list into a NumPy array:

```
arr_a = numpy.array([(2, 16), (24, 26)])
arr_b = numpy.array([(18, 8), (30, 22)])
```

This is the code compiled in Cython that I use:

```
%%cython

import numpy
cimport numpy
cimport cython
ctypedef numpy.int_t DTYPE_t

def do_iter(numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] arr_a, numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] arr_b):
    for a in arr_a:
        for b in arr_a:
            if a != b:
                for i in arr_b:
                    for j in arr_b:
                        if i != j:
                            print(a,b,i,j)
```

I expect the following output:

```
(2, 16) (24, 26) (18, 8) (30, 22)
(2, 16) (24, 26) (30, 22) (18, 8)
(24, 26) (2, 16) (18, 8) (30, 22)
(24, 26) (2, 16) (30, 22) (18, 8)
```

At first, I got the following Error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` Then I modified the code into:

```
do_iter(arr_a.any(),arr_b.any())
```

But it produced another error: `TypeError: Argument 'arr_a' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got numpy.bool_)` I suspect that I define the wrong NumPy type or dimension. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first error you got, you have to wrap the comparisons with `.any()` rather than changing the input.

```
...
if (a!=b).any():
...
if (i!=j).any():
...
```

This error is because `a!=b` will give you something like `(True, False)` since its a comparisons of 2 of 1x2 arrays. If you want the condition to be True if either of the 2 elements is different use `.any()` like the above. But if you want the condition to be True if both of the elements have to be different, change the above to `.all()`